# Clicking button on website and downloading data file into Excel

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I'm trying to download data from a website and put it into my excel file.

Here are the steps to what I'm trying to do:

1) go to website: http://www.housepriceindex.ca/default.aspx

2) click on "Download Historical Data (.xls)" (I'm stuck here)

3)input email address at bottom (abc@abc.com)

4)click accept

5)transfer the data from the just downloaded .xls file to my file.

**Here is the code so far**:

```
Sub GetData()


Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "http://www.housepriceindex.ca/default.aspx" 

Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
Do Until IE.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop

IE.Document.GetElementByID(lnkTelecharger2).Click


End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `IE.Document.GetElementByID("lnkTelecharger2").Click` quotes missing.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what I would do:

```
Sub GetData()
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim objElement As HTMLObjectElement

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.housepriceindex.ca/default.aspx"
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
    .Document.getElementById("lnkTelecharger2").Click
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
    Set HTMLDoc = .Document
    Set objElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("txtEmailDisclaimerEN")
    objElement.Value = "Email Address"
    Set objElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("lnkAcceptDisclaimerEN")        
    objElement.Click

    ' ... Get CSV somehow ...

    .Quit
End With

Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Now obviously that still leaves you with the issue of capturing the CSV- I tried a number of different ways to set a workbook variable to the CSV with no luck... the issue is that the button that you click doesn't contain the URL for the CSV you are going to be downloading, so unless someone else knows how to capture a file that's being prompted to open or save this is as far as I can help you..

Regards,
TheSilkRoad

Comment: Thanks. I keep getting an error on the first line: compile error: user defined type not defined. How do I fix this?

Comment: Microsoft Internet Controls (shdocvw.dll) and
'Microsoft HTML object Library. Got it, thanks dude!

Comment: Good, glad to help.

Comment: turns out when you download it, for a split second, a url appears. So I used that. I've got another site with this same problem, stumbled upon anything since the post?

Comment: Hey @RageAgainstheMachine , where does the URL appear? I wasn't able to get the URL through the code but if you could tell me how you got the URL then that was the missing piece to what you are trying to do... Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

You can target the button by its classname (`button small download`) :

```
IE.document.querySelector(".button.small.download").Click
```

or

```
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button small download")(0).Click
```

---

**BUT:**

If you know your way around JSON you can avoid login completely. There is a JSON link above the button you are seeking to click:

**data-data_url:**

[image: data]

You can use that with an [XMLHTTPRequest](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) to grab the JSON data and then parse the response with a tool such as [JSONConverter.](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). After you have added the .bas to your project you need to go VBE>Tools>References and add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime.

Here is just an outline showing the process of setting the initial JSON object and extracting some info.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim strURL As String, strJSON As String, Http As Object, json As Object
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    strURL = "https://housepriceindex.ca/_data/indx_data.json?d=4dfb05da"

    Set Http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With Http
        .Open "GET", strURL, False
        .send
        strJSON = .responseText
    End With
    Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(strJSON)

    Dim key As Variant, dictKeys As Variant
    '****************************************
    ' Set json = json("data") ' Array("indx", "spc", "indx_ch", "spc_ch", "Meta", "Data") '<== These are the keys in that dict.

    Set json = json("profiles")                  ' Array("c11", "mc","ab_calgary","ab_edmonton","bc_abbotsford","bc_kelowna" , _
                                                 "bc_vancouver","bc_victoria","mb_winnipeg","ns_halifax","on_barrie" , _
                                                 "on_brantford","on_guelph","on_hamilton","on_kingston","on_kitchener", _
                                                 "on_london","on_oshawa","on_ottawa","on_peterborough","on_st_catharines" , _
                                                 "on_sudbury","on_thunder_bay","on_toronto","on_windsor","qc_montreal","qc_quebec_city") '<==Keys in profile dict

    Dim dict As Object, rowNumber As Long
    Set dict = json("qc_montreal")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For Each key In dict
             rowNumber = rowNumber + 1
            .Cells(rowNumber, 1) = key
            .Cells(rowNumber, 2) = dict(key)
        Next key
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

**Sample sheet output:**

[image: Data sample]

---

**Sample source JSON:**

[image: Sample]

There is a lot of `C11` info in the second level dictionary housed under the top level dictionary (`"JSON"`) key `"data"`.

[image: data]